# Recursive function to find remainder when number is divided by 11

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I should program a recursive function to find remainder of a number when divided by 11 and I have to use the rule below:

for example, for number 918392:

F(918392) = F(2-9+3-8+1-9) = F(-20) = 11 - F(20) = 11 - F(0-2) = 11 - F(-2) = 11 - (11 - F(2)) = 11 - (11-2) = 2

I believe my code is correct but while submitting, it gives Run Time Error for 4/9 test cases.
Any recommendation to improve my code??;< Thanks!

```
def rem(number):
    sum = 0
    j = -1
    for i in range(0, len(number)):
        sum = sum + (-1)**(i) * int(number[j])
        j = j - 1
        
        
    if 0 <= sum < 11:
        return sum
    
    else:
        return 11 - rem(str(abs(sum)))
    
    
    
number = str(input())
print(rem(number))
```

Comment: Why start with `F(153728)` ? and your function is not recursive unless `reload` is a typo.

Comment: @SomeDude Oh you are right! I renamed the function name and forgot to fix that. Thank you. What do you mean? I meant if the number was an input, the algorithm of my function should work like that.

Comment: Is this about 918392 or about 153728? Can you please fix or clarify?

Comment: @trincot sorry for causing misunderstanding, i fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case "`sum` negative" is not handled correctly.
Edit: the last version corrects an error mrntioned by @trincot

I have also avoided the call to exponentiation

```
# The case "`sum` negative" is not handled correctly
# I have also avoided the call to exponentiation 

def rem(number):
    sum = 0
    j = -1
    coef = 1
    for i in range(0, len(number)):
        sum = sum + coef * int(number[j])
        j = j - 1
        coef = -coef
        
    if (sum < 0):
        return rem(str(11 - rem(str(-sum))))

        
    if 0 <= sum < 11:
        return sum
    
    return rem(str(sum))
    
    
n = input()
number = str(n)
print(rem(number))
print(int(n)%11)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to write it.

Comment: I corrected the error mentioned by @trincot

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

- The subtraction from 11 should only happen when `sum` is negative, if however `sum` is 11 or more (positive), then you should make the recursive call, but not "invert" it by subtracting it from 11.
- In the case where you *do* have to subtract it from 11, there is a possibility that the recursive call returns 0, and so 11 - 0 becomes 11, which is not an acceptable return value. In that case you should return 0. So you need to detect that situation.

Here is the corrected version of that `if...else` construct:

```
if 0 <= sum < 11:
    return sum
elif sum < 0:
    sum = 11 - rem(str(-sum))
    return 0 if sum == 11 else sum
else:
    return rem(str(sum))
```

Side note: `sum` is a native Python function. Consider using a different name for your variable.

With that note taken into account, some optimisations, support for negative numbers, and allowing the argument to be of either string or number type, the code can become:

```
def rem(number):
    total = int(number)
    if total >= 0:
        total = 0
        sign = 1
        for dig in reversed(str(number)):
            total += sign * int(dig)
            sign = -sign
        
    if total < 0:
        total = 11 - rem(-total)
        return 0 if total == 11 else total
    return total if total < 11 else rem(total)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this problem out. Was very helpful.

Comment: A detail on terminology: what you return is the modulo, not the remainder. The remainder of a negative number is negative normally. But OP post is not clear on this point.

Comment: Besides, I ackknowledge the fact that your answer was published before mine, and not with the result= 11 error. +1 to compensate a little bit. My motivation here was to write my first python code, with about no knowledge of Python. Just a little fun challenge.